# How can we find a basic feasible solution given the optimal value?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Suppose we have an LP in the form  max $w^{T}x$ subject to $Ax=b$ and $x \geq 0$. We are given that $M=\max\{w^{T}x : Ax=b\}$. Given knowledge of $M$, how can we can we find a basic feasible solution $x^{*}$ such that $Ax^{*}=b$ and $w^{T}x^{*}=M$?

I tried constructing the dual LP, but I'm not sure if that helps.

Comment: I don't believe that knowing the objective value of the optimal solution makes the general problem of *finding* an optimal solution any easier...

Comment: @math1000 It is very valuable information in the general case, it allows you to do branching and bounding as well as eliminate local optima.